# How do I add chat colors?

Tags: java, bukkit

I want to add color formats to my plugin (like essentials has colors in chat). For example, `&6test` would become *"test"* in gold.

I almost added those colors, but I have a problem. It deletes the whole message and leaves the green test message. How do I add colors?

Right now I'm using this:

```
public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent chatevent){
    for (String word : chatevent.getMessage().split(" ")){
        word = word.replaceAll("&2", "§2test");
        chatevent.setMessage(word);
        if(SysMng.getConfig().getStringList("badwords").contains(word)){
            if (!chatevent.getPlayer().hasPermission("bypassbadwords")){
            chatevent.setCancelled(true);
            chatevent.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Dont use dirty or swear words!");
         }
      }
    }
 }
```

But, like I said, it deletes the whole message and leaves the green test message. This is caused by:

```
word = word.replaceAll("&2", "§2test");
chatevent.setMessage(word);
```

Ignore the "badwords" part, it is just to prevent people from using swear words. How do I fix this so that players could use colors codes in chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to translate color codes (from an `&` symbol, for example), you can use [`ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/ChatColor.html#translateAlternateColorCodes(char,%20java.lang.String))

```
ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', str);
```

This will automatically convert all `&` color codes to color codes with the `§` symbol, and therefor to its respective `ChatColor`.

So, for example, if you used

```
String original = "&atest";
String formatted = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', original);
```

`formatted` would be equal to `"§atest"`, which is equal to `ChatColor.GREEN + "test"`.

If you wanted to allow players to chat using the `&` color codes, you could first listen for `AsyncPlayerChatEvent` (inside of a class that [`implements Listener`](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference#Adding_the_listener)), and then set the message to the correctly colored message using `.translateAlternateColorCodes`

```
@EventHandler
public void playerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e){
    //get the chat message
    String original = e.getMessage();

    //format the chat message with &colorCodes
    String formatted = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', original);

    //set the message to the formatted message
    e.setMessage(formatted);
}
```

Using this, if a player typed something like *"&6Hello, &aWorld!"*, it would be translated to `ChatColor.GOLD + "Hello, " + ChatColor.GREEN + "World!"`.

The reason the entire message is being replaced by *"§2test"* is because you're splitting the string up, and not reconstructing it.

Instead, you should split the string up ***after*** you use [`translateAlternateColorCodes`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/ChatColor.html#translateAlternateColorCodes(char,%20java.lang.String)), and then strip the colors from the string using [`ChatColor.stripColor(String)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/ChatColor.html#stripColor(java.lang.String)) before checking if it's a curse word (this would prevent players from bypassing the censor by putting color codes in front of curse words)

Comment: Soo how would my code look like i dont understand. How can i use it? where do i put it.

Comment: @Reaper123 Just whenever you want to change `&ahi` to `§ahi`, for example, you can use `ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', stringToFormat)`. Take a look at the last example of the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `ChatColor.{COLORNAME}`.

Example:
`word = word.replaceAll("&2", ChatColor.GREEN + "test");`

A complete list of all available color codes are here: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/ChatColor.html

You might have to import `org.bukkit.ChatColor` like this:
`import org.bukkit.ChatColor;`

**EDIT:** As for the reason why it's not replacing the correct part, it has nothing to do with colors. You are using the `.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` which takes a regex, since you don't care about regexs, just use the `.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` function. It will still replace all occurrences of the string.

**EDIT2:** You are also calling `chatevent.setMessage(word);` for every word, you want to call this only once you have processed all the words. Use a StringBuilder and append each word to it and then set the message at the end (out of the for loop).

Comment: its the same as word = word.replaceAll("&2", "§2test"); it still wont fix my problem.

Comment: I think I've solved it in the edit.

Never mind, I found another error, it's mentioned in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your deconstructing the String with multiple words in it. What you need to do is create an additional string and re-compile the message within your loop. Then do your: chatevent.setMessage(newly_contructed_message_from_your_loop);

But I would imagine whatever you are using you might have to separate them into multiple different objects to create the message from within the loop.